# Why node.js does not wait till comeback is done (_search request in to elasticsearch)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, callback

My code:

```
    client.search({
        index: _index,
        type: _type,
        body: {
            "query": {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": _typeChild,
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "id": "QASWED"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        temp['worker'] = resp.hits.hits[0]._source.name;
    });
```

If i set a breakpoint on

```
    temp['worker'] = resp.hits.hits[0]._source.lastCharacterName;
```

everything work correct.

Right after this query i have

```
    res.send(result);
```

Comment: You need to move `res.send(result);` in the `then(...)` block.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how JavaScript promises work, your

```
res.send(result);
```

is running faster than the ElasticSearch query, if you would move the res.send() 
function to the then() scope, it would work, i.e.

```
client.search({
    index: _index,
    type: "users",
    body: {
        "query": {
            "has_child": {
                "type": "items",
                "query": {
                    "match": {
                        "id": temp['id']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function(resp) {
    temp['seller'] = resp.hits.hits[0]._source.lastCharacterName;
    // process the temp['seller'] object there the way like you do it now (i.e. move this logic to this scope) so it will populate the result object
    res.send(result);
});
```